# hola podrian decirme cual es mi error?

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase donde tengo los metodos de actulizar, eliminar e insertar todos me funcionan bien menos el metodo de actualizar por aqui les dejo mi codigo y estoy usando c# y sql server 2008 r

Hola este es mi codigo que tengo en la clase coneccion:

```
class Conexion

{

   private string cadena = "Data Source=DESARROLLO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bdseguro;Integrated Security=True";



    public SqlConnection cn;

    private SqlCommandBuilder cmb;

    public DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public SqlDataAdapter da;

    public SqlCommand comando;



    private void conectar()



    {

        cn = new SqlConnection(cadena);

    }







    public Conexion()

    {

         conectar();

    }







    ////Consultar por partes

    //public DataSet ds= new DataSet();

    //public SqlDataAdapter da;



    public void consultar(string sql, string tabla)

    {

        ds.Tables.Clear();

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);

        cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        da.Fill(ds,tabla);

    }







    public bool eliminar(string tabla, string condicion)

    {

        cn.Open();

        string sql = "Delete from " + tabla + " where " + condicion;

        comando = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close();

        if (i > 0)

        {

            return true;

        }

        else

        {

            return false;



        }



    }









    public bool actualizar(string tabla, string campos, string condicion)

    {

        cn.Open();

        string sql = "Update  from " + tabla + " set " + " where " + condicion ;

        comando = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close();

        if (i > 0)

        {

            return true;

        }

        else

        {

            return false;



        }



    }







    //Consultar tablas

    public DataTable consultar2(string tabla)

    {

        string sql = "Select * FROM " + tabla;

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);

        DataSet dts = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(dts, tabla);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = dts.Tables[tabla];

        return dt;

    }







    //Insertar



    public bool insertar (string sql)

    {





        cn.Open();

        comando = new SqlCommand(sql,cn);

        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close();

        if (i > 0)

        {

            return true;

        }





        else



        {



            return false;



        }

    }

































}
```

}

aqui lo uso en un formulario:

```
string campos = "Descripcion ='" + this.TxtParentesco.Text  +"',Activo ='" + Nivel +"'";

        if (obDatos.actualizar("Tipo_de_Parentesco", campos, " id_parentesco ='" + this.TxtId.Text + "'"))

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Registro Actualizado Exitosamente");



        }

        else

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar Actualizar");

        }



        }





         Application.Restart();
```

No has compartido ningún código onde podamos ver el error.

y aqui esta mi error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

c#

Comment: Marcos, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Porfavor lee todo lo que puedas del centro de ayuda y despues ven a [edit] tu pregunta y agrega un [mcve].

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis en tu UPDATE https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Soy novato en c#. esta parte donde la puedo declarar: Dictionary<string, string> campos = new Dictionary<string, string>();
campos.Add("columna1","valor");
campos.Add("columna2","otro valor");

Comment: el error que te arroja decía "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'". Tu error esta en la sentencia sql que casualmente la variable que la contiene tiene el nombre sql, revisa el string que se genera en esa variable y veras el error

Answer (score 2):

No defines correctamente **los valores de set en el método actualizar**

En tu código tienes lo siguiente:

```
public bool actualizar(string tabla, string campos, string condicion)
{
    cn.Open();
    string sql = "Update  from " + tabla + " set " + " where " + condicion;

    comando = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    if (i > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

y en la variable a set no le das ningún valor:

```
string sql = "Update  from " + tabla + " set " + " where " + condicion;
```

Hay varias opciones de solucionarlo, aunque yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

Pasarle como segundo parámetro al método actualizar un dictionary que tendrá cada clave-valor de los set a modificar, luego iterar sobre este para añadirlo al set, algo como lo siguiente:

```
public bool actualizar(string tabla, Dictionary<string,string> campos, string condicion) {
    cn.Open();

    string sql = "Update  from " + tabla;
    if (campos.Count > 0) {
        sql = sql + " set";
        foreach(string item in campos) {
            sql = sql + " " + item.Key + "=" + item.Value ",";
        }
        // Quitamos la ultima coma
        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 1);
    }

    sql = sql + " where " + condicion;

    comando = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    if (i > 0) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Para utilizarlo:

```
Dictionary<string, string> campos = new Dictionary<string, string>();
campos.Add("columna1","valor");
campos.Add("columna2","otro valor");

 if (obDatos.actualizar("Tipo_de_Parentesco", campos, " id_parentesco ='" + this.TxtId.Text + "'")) {
    // codigo
 }
```

Comment: Favor de no usar la zona de respuestas para hacer preguntas o pedir aclaraciones al OP

Comment: Hola Ruben ya puede ver la informacion?  ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/242898/119634 aqui esta parte de mi informacion